# onchange function when selecting drop down menu will populate a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is my table in the database

tbl_job_title

```
ID | Job_title    | description     | 
1  | Accountant   | Handle Accounts |
2  | Dev. Support | Support Centre  |
```

when selecting the job title from the table, i'm using a drop down menu and here is my code.

```
<select id="job_title" >
   <option value=""> </option>
     <?php foreach ($job_title as $row): ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?>
       </option>
     <?php endforeach?>
</select>
```

and I have a textbox that will populate if i select a job_title

```
<input type="text" id="catch_value">
```

How do I populate the textbox when I select example is "Accountant", the textbox value must be "Handle Accounts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the short & sweet code I have made just for you, feel free to use it!
Not required Ajax...

**CODE -**

```
<select id="job_title" >
   <option value="" class="job" role=""> </option>
     <?php foreach ($job_title as $row): ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="job<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" role="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?>
       </option>
     <?php endforeach?>
</select>
```

**Jquery -**

```
$('#job_title').on('change',function(){
    var m = this.value;
    var n = $('.job'+m).attr('role');
    $('#catch_value').val(n);
    return false;
});
```

eg - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPE9r/30/)

Comment: thanks for the try but i need is that when i input "Accountant" the textbox will populate "Handle Accounts" like in the example above, i'm connecting in the database. thansk

Comment: @Vincent now i have updated my code & also try new fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TPE9r/5/

Comment: @Vincent need to write role="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>"

Comment: i have a question. why do i need class for="job" ? i'm using for each

Comment: can i remove the class ? i have an error here and i alerted the (n) value http://jsfiddle.net/TPE9r/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47827/discussion-between-vincent-and-rohit-suthar-mumbai)

Comment: @Vincent please check the chat.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="job_title" onchange="javascript:callajaxvalue(this.value);">
   <option value=""> </option>
     <?php foreach ($job_title as $row): ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?>
       </option>
     <?php endforeach?>
</select>

<script>
    function callajaxvalue(id)
    {
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "some.php",
           data: { id: id}
            success: function(data, textStatus ){
                if(data)
                { $("#catch_value").val(data);}
            },
          })
    }
</script>
```

**some.php**

$_POST['id'];

$query = "get data from table";

execute query.

echo $row['description'];

**For codeigniter**

```
function callajaxvalue(id)
    {
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "my_controller/update/"+id,
           data: { id: id}
            success: function(data, textStatus ){
                if(data)
                { $("#catch_value").val(data);}
            },
          })
    }
```

**my_Controller.php**

```
    public function update()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $data['discription'] = call model function for get data form database

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: do you have a sample of this in jsfiddle?

Comment: this to much easy to implement. what kind of problem you facing. where is confusion in this code?

Comment: i am confused in some.php, i'm using codeigniter. sorry

Comment: do you have other options instead of ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#job_title').change(function(){
  $('#catch_value').val('Handle Accounts');
 });
```

see fiddle:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPE9r/2/)

or you can add if statments

```
 $('#job_title').change(function(){
    var jt = $('#job_title').val();
if(jt == "Something")
{
  $('#catch_value').val('Handle Accounts');
}
if (jt == "SomethingElse")
{
   $('#catch_value').val('somethingelse');
}
 });
```

Comment: That will just set it to "Handle Accounts" not matter which `<option>` is selected

Comment: the value is from the database. how should i get the value ?

Comment: so you want the input text value to be the same as the option value selected ?

Comment: No, the input text value would be the description, from the database. Did you even read the question?

Comment: if you are going to get other data, you would need ajax to call the db to get the description value.  as Niles just answered.

Comment: @bart2puck no. i have an example in my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right answer :

```
    <select id="job_title" onchange='populate()'>
   <option value=""> </option>
    <?php foreach ($job_title as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?>
   </option>
 <?php endforeach?>
  </select>

   <script>
       function populate(){
        var jobttl= document.getElementById('job_title').value();
        if(jobttl){
          document.getElementById('catch_value').value;
        }

        }
   </script>
```

Comment: do you have a sample jsfiddle for this ?